# How to create Tax rule programmatically in controller magento 2

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, tax, rules, object-manager

I have try with this code make tax rule programmatically. but it's not working infact model not loaded. you can see this code :

```
$objectManagers = \Magento\TestFramework\Helper\Bootstrap::getObjectManager();
$fixtureTaxRule = $objectManagers->create('Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation\Rule');
```

i have get this error :

```
Class 'Magento\TestFramework\Helper\Bootstrap' not found
```

can you please suggest how can i create tax rule ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally i have solve this issue. Now you can use this code and i hope it's also beneficial for you guys.

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $fixtureTaxRule = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation\Rule::class);
 $fixtureTaxRule->setCode("Test");
 $fixtureTaxRule->setPriority(0);
 $fixtureTaxRule->setCustomerTaxClassIds(array(3));
 $fixtureTaxRule->setProductTaxClassIds(array(2));
 $fixtureTaxRule->setTaxRateIds(array(3));
 $fixtureTaxRule->save();
```

Comment: Hi, Can you please share your whole code in your answer?

Answer (score 2):

Using object manager is not allowed so answer above seems to be wrong.

Correct answer can be found in setup/src/Magento/Setup/Fixtures/TaxRulesFixture.php in setTaxMode method.

taxRateFactory and taxRateRepository together with taxRuleFactory and taxRuleRepository should be used.

```
    //Add Tax Rate for selected Tax Mode
    /** @var $taxRate TaxRateInterface */
    $taxRate = $this->taxRateFactory->create();
    $taxRate->setCode($taxMode)
        ->setRate(self::DEFAULT_TAX_RATE)
        ->setTaxCountryId(self::DEFAULT_TAX_COUNTRY)
        ->setTaxPostcode('*');

    $taxRateData = $this->taxRateRepository->save($taxRate);

    //Add Tax Rule for Tax Mode
    /** @var $taxRuleDataObject TaxRuleInterface */
    $taxRuleDataObject = $this->taxRuleFactory->create();
    $taxRuleDataObject->setCode($taxMode)
        ->setTaxRateIds([$taxRateData->getId()])
        ->setCustomerTaxClassIds([self::DEFAULT_CUSTOMER_TAX_CLASS_ID])
        ->setProductTaxClassIds([self::DEFAULT_PRODUCT_TAX_CLASS_ID])
        ->setPriority(0)
        ->setPosition(0);

    $this->taxRuleRepository->save($taxRuleDataObject);
```